# How do I implement client-side bandwidth throttling for FTP/HTTP?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, bandwidth

I am tasked with writing a client-side data download system (on Linux) that uses FTP or HTTP to download terabyte-sized data from external partners to our local site. Our company's network admin tells me that I cannot exceed a certain bandwidth. What is the best way for me to implement such a system? Do existing libraries exist?

I am open to writing my own FTP and HTTP clients (in either C or Java on Linux) but would prefer to stay out of the kernel. I know that I can limit the rate at which my FTP/HTTP client calls a socket read(), but what happens if the server-side calls write() faster than my limit?

Comment: As long as you are using TCP/IP the server will not send something faster than you read I think. The cliont have to ACK a packet before the server can send another one.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about TCP's flow control, so that answers that part. But I am still looking for the best approach to implementing throttling overall.

Comment: Read something, use the packet size to calculate the sleep time, and read again is on top of my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build another layer on top of an `InputStream`: In the `read` method, you can count the bytes so far. If the number of bytes/second exceed a certain limit, let the download thread sleep for a while. TCP's flow control does the rest.

Comment: Don't you mean to perform the sleep in the read() method of the InputStream (the one that reads from the socket)?

Comment: That's better. Actually I have looked in my *upload* throttling code I have implemented some time ago. Probably both works, but yes, it's looks better to put in a read(). I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know Apache JMeter simulates slow connections. You could maybe take look at [the code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/SlowSocket.java).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the network path delay you could just set your TCP receive buffer size to the desired bandwidth-delay product. That will throttle the sender all right. But the resulting value may be too small for your platform, so it may adjust it upwards. Check the value after you set it.

Does your netadmin know that TCP automatically shares bandwidth fairly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to off the shelf GUI or command line products? Filezillia provides this. 
There also is a linux command line client called lftp. A settable parameter is net:limit-total-rate which will limit the rate of transfer. Since this client supports multiple transfers at one time, it also has a parameter net:limit-rate.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, if you are on linux you just could use `wget` instead of re-inventing the wheel? Take a look at the `--limit-rate` switch.

But back on topic :) This answer could get you started: [How can I implement a download rate limited in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761823/how-can-i-implement-a-download-rate-limited-in-java)